# How do I hide both scroll bars of wx.ListCtrl in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

As my list grows there are scrollbars. 
I want to hide them.
How do I do it for wx.ListCtrl in wxPython?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to hide horizontal scrollbar by implementing my own `ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin` with `EVT_LIST_COL_DRAGGING` event bound, so that columns always fill the client size width and don't go further.

(Actually, I took the code for custom `ListCtrl` from [this](https://coldfix.de/2015/10/05/autosized-listctrl/) topic and made some adjustments to it. I will post a link to a gist with my code later, if needed - right now it's so terribly commented!)

Not sure, but, maybe, this will be helpful in your situation:

[how to hide the Vertical and horizontal Scrollbars with wxPython ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459033/how-to-hide-the-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars-with-wxpython)

P.S. I didn't expect auto-sized columns to be that difficult in wxPython. Does anyone know if it is anyhow easier to do the same stuff in PyQt, Tkinter or Kyvi? I managed to try them out for a little, but I always got stuck somewhere before managing multi-dimensional lists for the desktop app I write.